# React Router connect to redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a basic site setup using `react-router`, my index page is:

```
render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Reducer:

```
import { ADD_DETAILS } from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = [
  {
    id: 0,
    language: '',
    session: '',
    values: '',
    accessCode: '',
    age: 0,
    gender: '',
    ethnicity: '',
    drinkOften: '',
    drinkConcern: '',
  },
];

export default function UserDetails(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_DETAILS:

    // update user details

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Index reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import UserDetails from './UserDetails';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    UserDetails,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

A typical page looks like this:

```
class Screen1 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
  }

  submitForm(e) {
    const language = e.target.value;

    //dispatch action here  - this.props.UserDetails
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="title">Please select your language</label>

        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          value="en"
          onClick={this.submitForm}>
          English
        </button>
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          value="po"
          onClick={this.submitForm}>
          Polszczyzna
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect()(Screen1);
```

I have added:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    UserDetails: state.UserDetails,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Screen1);
```

In my actions I have this `addDetails` action, how can I dispatch it from my page:

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionTypes';

export const addDetails = (id, text, time) => ({
    type: types.ADD_DETAILS,
    text,
    id,
    time,
});
```

How can I dispatch an action in my page? I can't see the dispatch in the props.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I recommend to use `redux-little-router` https://github.com/FormidableLabs/redux-little-router it's really decent solution for accessing routes.

- Use `mapStateToProps` to map your data into properties of component, so that would be always prepared and provided as needed. But please be aware that you would not need component to be rerendered each time you're changing store. That's why you should use `reselect` as well https://github.com/reactjs/reselect
- Use `mapDispatchToProps` to build up a handlers for dispatching jobs, here is where actions should be taken

You should be having something like this:

```
import { addDetails } from '../constants/Actions';

export default connect(

  // mapStateToProps
  (state, ownProps) => {
      return {
          userId: ownProps.user.id
      }
  },

  // mapDispatchToProps
  (dispatch, ownProps) => {
      return {
          onUserActionButtonClick: (id, text, time) => dispatch(addDetails(id, text, time))
      }
  }

)(Screen1);
```

Not just bind that function which your component

```
class Screen1 extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.submitForm = this.submitForm.bind(this);
  }

  submitForm(e) {
    const language = e.target.value;

    const { userId, onUserActionButtonClick } = this.props

    onUserActionButtonClick(userId, language, new Date);

    //dispatch action here  - this.props.UserDetails
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="title">Please select your language</label>

        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          value="en"
          onClick={this.submitForm}>
          English
        </button>
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          value="po"
          onClick={this.submitForm}>
          Polszczyzna
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mapsDispatchToProps`of react-redux.
Like it is shown here [mapDispatchToProps](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md).

Essentially all the actions and state are mapped in the props for your page.

Comment: I cant see my actions to dispatch them, `this.props.addDetails` is empty

Comment: You have only added mapStateToProps and not mapsDispatchToPropsof